# Ошибка при попытках организовать кнопку назад в WebView?

Tags: android, eclipse

Вот код полностью весь. Все расписано.
Прошу помочь готовыми решениями, так как общие фразы не особо понятны для меня, как ну уж очень начинающего хацкера. Спасибо за помощь и понимание.
Место ошибки пометил как: //---строка ошибки
Сама ошибка: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method canGoBack() from the type WebView"

```
package com.magnum.farm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Поиск AdView как ресурса и отправка запроса.
        final AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //открытие веб ресурса (локальный или в сети)
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://сайт.ру");

        //открытие ссылок в самом приложении
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i("", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading url=" + url);               
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i("", "onPageFinished url=" + url);             
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });

        //Скрытие места для рекламы если нету интернета
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
        { @Override public void onAdLoaded() { 
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } });}

        //ремонт кнопки МЕНЮ
        @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        // никак не обрабатывать
        return true; }

          //обработка кнопки назад (засунул сюда так как были дубликаты и еще больше ошибок)
//---строка ошибки    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && WebView.canGoBack()) { 
//---строка ошибки         WebView.goBack(); 
        return true; }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

ошибка: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method canGoBack() from the type WebView"

Почему бы вам начинающему не начать обращаться к документации или хотя бы прочитать пару книг по основам языка?

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к обычному методу как к статическому. Другими словами, не статический метод canGoBack() может быть вызван только у экземпляра класса, но не у самого класса.

Comment: так а что мне конкретно нужно сделать в этой ситуации?? Напишите пож-та норм типа то туда епремести, то туда допиши. Спасибо. Пока вы будете писать советы, быстрее будет наеврное просто дать кусок готового кода) Спасибо, кстати. очень признателен, что откликнулись!!

Comment: Ну, я вот так вслепую не смогу, можете попробовать при объявлении метода canGoBack() объявить его статическим.
Я так полагаю, в вашем случае будет что-то типа  
public static boolean canGoBack()

Comment: Вы уж извините, что такой вопрос задал, просто мне это ужно для шаблона, дальше все я буду строить на HTML5, в котором лучше немного разбираюсь + онлайн игры.

Comment: Понял вас, успехов.